# ASP.Net Gridview search returns incorrect index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have made a gridview table as shown below:
[image]

The problem is upon searching, my table is returning incorrect index i.e. 0. I understand this is becuase my table on searching only returns one row which is hence at index 0. But I'm having trouble in fixing this issue. I want the original index of the value in the table.

This is my function that triggers on clicking "Search":

```
public void searchDatabaseForMedicine()
    {
        String medicineNameTxt = medicineName.Text;


        int Found;

        if (medicineNameTxt != "" || medicineNameTxt != null)
        {
            Found = myAccount.SearchMedicineStock(medicineNameTxt, ref dataTable);

            if (Found > 0)
            {
                medicineDatabase.DataSource = dataTable;
                medicineDatabase.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                medicineDatabase.DataSource = null;
                medicineDatabase.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is called when I select a tab (This is the one returning wrong index) in the value 'int':

```
protected void medicineDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int index = int.Parse(medicineDatabase.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        selectedList.Add(index);

        GridViewRow row = medicineDatabase.SelectedRow;



        Label medicineLabel = (Label) medicineDatabase.Rows[index].FindControl("lblMedicine");
        Label costLabel = (Label) medicineDatabase.Rows[index].FindControl("lblPrice");

        Label vendorLabel = (Label)medicineDatabase.Rows[index].FindControl("lblVendor");

        //int costVal = int.Parse(cost.Text);
        String medicineNameTxt = medicineLabel.Text;
        String fullfilledBy = vendorLabel.Text;

        float costFloat = float.Parse(costLabel.Text);

        user = Request.QueryString["user"];

        String cnic = myAccount.getCNIC(user);


        myAccount.addMedicineOrderItem(cnic, costFloat, medicineNameTxt, fullfilledBy);


    }
```

This is SearchMedicineStock:

```
public int SearchMedicineStock(String Name, ref DataTable DT)
    {
        int Found = 0;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("searchMedicineStock ", connection); //name of your procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@medicine", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Found", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            // set parameter values
            cmd.Parameters["@medicine"].Value = Name;


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // read output value 
            Found = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Found"].Value); //convert to output parameter to interger format

            if (Found == 1)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

                {
                    da.Fill(dataSet);

                }

                DT = dataSet.Tables[0];

            }


            connection.Close();


        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return Found;

    }
```

Any ideas please?
Thank You!

Comment: I don't see anything that operates on or references an index. Is that what `Found` is supposed to be? If so can we see the code in `SearchMedicineStock`?

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm sorry I omitted my selectedIndex_Changed function. Hope it's fine now?

Comment: int index = int.Parse(medicineDatabase.SelectedIndex.ToString()); do you find problem in this line, if yes what output are you expecting..

Comment: Yes there is a problem in this line. For example lets say I searched the table for a specific medicine that is at index 4. Due to searching, my table only returns one row which is always index 0, in contrast to the fact that the original index is 4 in the database. How can I get the original index instead of index 0? I hope its clear now.